# Android Studio can't run program due to emulator not working

Tags: android, emulation, haxm

I have been following a tutorial to make my first program on android studios, but now that I have finished the program, I can't actually see if it works or not because when I click run and choose an emulator it says "must download Intel Haxm..." and I have downloaded and everything.. just cant get it to work. Is there any other way I can like open my program on a different application to see if the code worked? I am extremely new to this but can't seem to get the emulator to work, after trying solutions suggested on other threads.

Comment: A) what is your dev env? B) HAXM (sometimes) requires a restart after installing. Have you done that? C) You could always plug an actual Android device and run your program on that.

Comment: Windows 7, I have restarted, and dont have an android :(

Comment: I agree with @JordanBondo. I would like to add 1 more thing: You might need to check if virtualization is enabled in BIOS settings. Just google this **"turn on virtualization in bios"**. Shouldn't be too hard, if it's disabled, proceed to enable it.

Comment: If enabling virtualization in your bios doesn't work, you could try an ARM emulator. HAXM is only needed if you are running a x86 emulator. Download one of the armeabi emulator images and see if that runs. At least that way you would know if the problem is really with the emulator or elsewhere.

Comment: One other thing to try is the Genymotion emulator. They run inside of VirtualBox (so you'll have to install that also). Free for individual, non-commercial use.

Comment: I just had to turn on the virtualization in the bios, thanks for that!